# Warning: Passing argument makes pointer from integer without a cast (-Wint-conversion)

Tags: c

Write a code that checks if two words entered by the user are anagrams.
   I managed to successfully write this program without calling separate functions, but when I tried to use separate functions (in this case the `void read_word` and the `bool equal_array`), I got the warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void read_word(int counts[26]);
bool equal_array(int counts1[26], int counts2[26]);

int main(void) /*Checks if two words entered by the user are anagrams */
{
    char ch;
    int counts1[26] = {0}, counts2[26] = {0};
    printf("Enter the first word: ");
    read_word(counts1[26]); /*Reads the first word and keeps track of its letter */

    printf("Enter the second word: ");
    read_word(counts2[26]); /*Reads the second word and keeps track of its letter */

    if (equal_array(counts1[26], counts2[26])) 
        printf("The words are anagram\n");
    else
        printf("The words are not anagram.\n");
    return 0;
}
void read_word(int counts[26]) 
{
    int i;
    char ch;
    scanf("%c", &ch);           /*Reads the word entered by the user*/
    while (ch != '\n') {
        counts[ch - 'a']++;     /*Keeps track of how many times a letter has been seen */
        scanf("%c", &ch);
    }
}

bool equal_array(int counts1[26], int counts2[26])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (counts1[i] != counts2[i]) { 
            return false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;  /*If the two arrays are identical, return true, otherwise return false */
}
```

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'read_word' makes pointer from integer
>   without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Comment: your call `equal_array(counts1[26], counts2[26])` is calling `equal_array` with `counts1[26]` which is the 26th element in `counts1` (out of bound). you should invoke with `equal_array(counts1, counts2)` to specify the arrays

Comment: Same comment apply for your `read_word` calls

Comment: @dvhh Thanks man I forgot when calling a function, the sizes are not included. much appreciated.